# Still receiving 401 unauthorized after including credentials : 'include' in HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, ember.js

I am new to Ember.js and I am currently working on a vehicle app. I have done the login part in which I have an HTTP Post request with fetch which has `credentials : 'include'` in the init object and send it to the server, which is remote. On a successful login the user is transitioned to the home page where there are three option buttons: vehicles, logout and Profile Data. Moreover, cookies are set as the login response has a set-cookie header. At the moment I am not using the vehicles button, but the other two do not work as expected. For them I have made two other http fetch request in which I have `credentials : 'include'` in the init object but I assume that I cannot access the cookies in which there is my `jsessionId`. I tried to read them with `document.cookie`, but it turned out that `jsessionId` is HTTP only which means that it cannot be accessed through JavaScript.

If I read the cookies, I could include them in my two fetch requests for logout and getUser I think that then the requests would be successful.

Am I right or not and what should I do ?

Here are some of my source files:

`components/login.js`

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { action } from "@ember/object";
import { tracked } from "@glimmer/tracking";
import {inject as service} from "@ember/service";

export default class LoginComponent extends Component{
  @tracked email;
  @tracked password;
  @service router;

  @action
  logUser(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let userData = {
        'email' : this.email,
        'password' : this.password
    };
    let fetchObject = {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers : {
            'Content-type' : 'application/json',
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(userData),
    };
    fetch('https://gara6.bg/auto-api/users/login', fetchObject)
        .then(response =>{
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data =>{
            if(data.statusCode == 'SUCCESS'){
                this.redirectHome(data);
            }
            else{
                throw Error('Check your data or connection');
            }
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            alert('Unable to log in ! ' + error);
        });
  }

  redirectHome(data){
      this.router.transitionTo('home');
  }

}
```

`components/login.hbs`

```
<form {{on 'submit' this.logUser}} id='login'>
    <label id="label" class="formElement" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <Input class="form-control formElement input" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" @value={{this.email}}/><br>
     <label id="label" for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <Input class="form-control formElement input" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" @value={{this.password}}/><br>
    <button id='loginLink' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg formElement ' type='submit'>Log In</button> 
</form>
```

templates/home.hbs:

```
<h1>Welcome User!</h1>
<OptionButtons/>
```

`components/option-buttons.hbs`:

```
<div class="buttonHolder">
    <button  class='btn btn-primary btn-lg homeButton' type='button' {{on 'click' this.logOut}}>Log Out</button><br>
    <button  class='btn btn-primary btn-lg homeButton' type='button'>Vehicles</button><br>
    <button  class='btn btn-primary btn-lg homeButton' type='button' {{on 'click' this.userMe}}>Profile Data</button><br> 
</div>
```

`components/option-buttons.js`

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { action } from "@ember/object";

export default class OptionButtonsComponent extends Component {

    @service router;

    @action
    userMe(){
      let fetchObject = {
          method: 'GET',
          credentials : 'include',
          headers : {
              'Content-type' : 'application/json',
          },
      };
      fetch('https://gara6.bg/auto-api/users/me', fetchObject)
          .then(response => {
              return response.json();
          })
          .then(data => {
              if(data.statusCode == 'SUCCESS'){
                 console.log(data.data);
              }
              else{
                  throw ('Check your internet connection');
              }
          })
          .catch(error =>{
              alert('Unable to Log out ! '+ error);
          });
    }

    @action
    logOut(){
        let fetchObject = {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials : 'include',
            headers : {
                'Content-type' : 'application/json',
            },
        };
        fetch('https://gara6.bg/auto-api/users/logout', fetchObject)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                if(data.statusCode == 'SUCCESS'){
                    this.backToLogin();
                }
                else{
                    throw ('Check your internet connection');
                }
            })
            .catch(error =>{
                alert('Unable to Log out ! '+ error);
            });
    }

    backToLogin() {
        this.router.transitionTo('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: how does your CORS response look like? It must send `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`! Also are you *sure* you need CORS and can not just use the ember proxy for development? It depends where you will deploy your app *on production*. It its the same server on production you probably dont want to use CORS.

Comment: @Lux, all three responses (for login, logout and getUser) send  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' . I am not familiar  enough with CORS and I have now idea what is ember proxy. It would be nice if you could explain them to me. I am working on this app, in order to get the basics  of Ember.js and I am not sure whether it will be deployed in the future.

Comment: Also, I noticed that even the the response for the login request sends set-cookie: ... when I look up at developer tools-> Application in the cookies section I cannot see the jsessionId , received from set-cookies header, so set-cookies may not work appropriately.

Comment: you can run `ember serve --proxy=http://example.com/` and the ember dev server will proxy all AJAX requests to `http://localhost:4200` to `example.com`. This allows you to develop without CORS, like your API and ember app come from the same origin. Also consider to join the ember community discord server for a more interactive help experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Error message displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jylH4.jpg)

So I managed to find out what blocked the cookies from being set properly.
It turned out that as the remote server was sending me the cookies my browser blocked them because they did not have the SameSite attribute so the browser marked it as SameSite=Lax and blocked them.

In order to prevent this cause I had to visit this url :
chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies
and then disable the SameSite by default cookies:

Here is an example:

[SameSite by default cookies: disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQlgb.png)